# Load data from Database once and available all the time using spring and show in JSP

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I want to Load Dropdown data from Database at once and set inside java object and tie to my view (JSP page ) and available all the time for that particular controller or functionality using spring mvc AND jsp pages.
I dont want to load on application start up as ours is big one and and each functionality is independent.
It takes a lot of time to start the application if i load on application start up
Is there a way to it using spring mvc pattern and using JSP
Could someone please let me know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

As you have not mentioned how frequently you are doing the database operation or how frequently you are fetching the data. Considering the average user.

**Approach: Create your own local cache/ program cache implementation.**

- Instead of loading all the data from the database during startup, load only master data which will be common for all. If master data is also high then you can perform the lazy loading approach.
- Load the data of a specific feature when it is requested for the first time. Keep the data in the local cache.
- Whenever someone is making the changes then add the data in the cache and save the same to the database. so you will always have latest data in the cache.

Advantage:

- Very useful for common or static master data
  -If you need good business logic for some common data. This way only once you are processing the data and keeping cache.
  -Fetching the data is very fast as it doesn't involve database request except for the first time

**Disadvantage:**

- If you have a very high number of users and a very high update operation then the updating cache will delay the update process as you need to update it sequentially.

I suggest you can use a combination of approaches to improve the code quality and processing.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a typical cache functionality.

Spring supports [caching out of the box](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/) by `@EnableCaching` on application level and `@Cacheable(“cachename”)` on the repository method retrieving your dropdown data. In your simple use case you not even need an additional framework as there is a `CacheManager` based on `ConcurrentHashMap` which simply caches for ever.

With caching in place your controller can simply fetch the dropdown data from the repository. Caching will ensure only the first call will really fetch from database and keeps the result in memory for all upcoming calls.

If you ever need more sophisticated caching you only have to exchange the cache manager and configure the cache for your needs.